# What does '@' do in this C Shell script?

Tags: csh

I have a third party C shell script that contains the line:

```
@ CM4_ON = $CM4_ON * 2
```

The script succeeds on a CentOS 7 system. What does '@' do in this context?

Comment: A script can succeed without every line in the script succeeding.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid `bash` command. Are you sure it's a bash script?

Comment: @jeremysprofile But it would print an error message for this line.

Comment: @Barmar "Poor man's debug command" (when they should've used `set -x`)

Comment: That's not a `bash` script (or at least, treated as a `bash` script, it runs a command named `@` with arguments `CM4_ON`, `=`, the expansion of `$CM4_ON`, the expansion of `*`, and `2`. There is nothing special about the word `@` in this context.)

Comment: @ is a shell special paramter but not sure in the way it's used here. Check https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#special_parameters_and_shell_variables

Comment: Maybe it's a custom function defined in the script like `@() (( $* ))`

Comment: Where, out of curiosity, is this script installed? That might provide a clue as to how it is *expected* to be used.

Comment: @Riz This has nothing to do with the special parameter `@`.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually a .csh script. Does that help?

Comment: @chepner, my bad. It was only to say '@' is a valid paramter but yeah, nothing to do with this.

Comment: Does this answers your question? [What does an '@' character mean in a csh script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518342/what-does-an-character-mean-in-a-csh-script)

Comment: @0stone0 Thanks, it does. It seems '@' is a shortened form of 'set', used for assignment, in C shell scripts.

Comment: See https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/csh.1.asp — and please search in the future (ie. “csh syntax”)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer in the comments. It seems '@' is a shortened form of 'set', used for assignment, in C shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, it is for integer arithmetic operations:

```
set x = 2 + 3

@   x = 2 + 3
```

The first sets `$x` to be `"2 + 3"`

The second set `$x` to be `5`

More useful (typically inside a loop or some other manipulation)...

```
@ n = 1 

@ n = n + 1
```

Sets `$n` to be `2`